# Has " they were" been left out before the "convicted" because of parallelism?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

others, less courageous or less inclined to self-assertion, sought rather to conceal their creed; but these latter were carefully sought out, both in the towns and in the country districts, and when convicted were relentlessly put to death.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Comment: The "predictably repeated" subject+verb highlighted in preceding *but **these latter were** carefully sought out* are both "deleted" before the word ***convicted***. And if you want to look at it that way, you could say the actual subject *(**others = the latter**)* is again deleted (but not the verb ***were***) *after* the word ***convicted*** (but if we *were* going to explicitly include a subject at that position, we'd probably use pronoun ***they*** rather than ***[those] others, the latter***).

Comment: The “were” wasn’t omitted!

Answer (score 0):

No. "Parallelism is the repetition of grammatical elements in writing and speaking".

One of the most well-known examples of parallelism is featured in Neil Armstrong’s statement, made as he stepped on the moon: “That’s one small step for man, one giant leap for mankind.” The structure of the two noun phrases in this sentence is similar due to the repeated use of “one.”

---

and when convicted were relentlessly put to death  *as opposed to*

and when **"they were"** convicted were relentlessly put to death.

the inclusion of **"they were"** is not necessary as we have already established earlier who we are talking about ie "others, less courageous or less inclined to self-assertion"

[Definition of Parallelism](https://literarydevices.net/parallelism/)